# Reversed distribution of dependent variable in Stata's quantile regression

Tags: distributions, stata, quantile-regression, dependent-variable

I am little confused by the fact that Stata seems to reverse the distribution of the dependent when calculating the quantile regression (any of the commands). When I look at the simple c.d.f. of my dependent, the value of the dependent at the 10th quantile is 2 and at the 90th quantile is 40. However, the output of the qreg, etc. command for the 90th quantile evaluates the effect at the 10th quantile of the c.d.f and vice versa. What is the reason for this reversal? Can I reverse the distribution somehow? I need that to construct some graphs, which do make much more sense if the distribution is as in the c.d.f. above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably comparing the adjusted quantiles to covariate-adjusted ones, though it is hard to know without seeing code and output.

Here's a *replicable* example showing that the two agree (without adding covariates):

```
sysuse auto, clear
sqreg price , q(.01 .05 .1 .25 .5 .75 .9 .95 0.99)
sum price , detail
cdfplot price , ylab(.01 .05 .1 .25 .5 .75 .9 .95 0.99) xline(3291 3748 3895 4195 5006.5 6342 11385 13466 15906, lcolor(gs15)) xlab(#12)
```

Perhaps you can modify this example if it does not clarify.

Here's the output:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. sqreg price , q(.01 .05 .1 .25 .5 .75 .9 .95 0.99)
(fitting base model)

Bootstrap replications (20)
----+--- 1 ---+--- 2 ---+--- 3 ---+--- 4 ---+--- 5 
....................

Simultaneous quantile regression                    Number of obs =         74
  bootstrap(20) SEs                                 .01 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000
                                                    .05 Pseudo R2 =     0.0057
                                                    .10 Pseudo R2 =     0.0014
                                                    .25 Pseudo R2 =     0.0001
                                                    .50 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000
                                                    .75 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000
                                                    .90 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000
                                                    .95 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000
                                                    .99 Pseudo R2 =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |              Bootstrap
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q01          |
       _cons |       3291   136.9281    24.03   0.000     3018.103    3563.897
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q05          |
       _cons |       3748   167.3149    22.40   0.000     3414.542    4081.458
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q10          |
       _cons |       3895   95.90142    40.61   0.000     3703.869    4086.131
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q25          |
       _cons |       4195   147.4865    28.44   0.000      3901.06     4488.94
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q50          |
       _cons |       5079   219.7195    23.12   0.000       4641.1      5516.9
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q75          |
       _cons |       6342   1051.021     6.03   0.000     4247.318    8436.682
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q90          |
       _cons |      11385   1248.294     9.12   0.000     8897.154    13872.85
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q95          |
       _cons |      13466   920.2476    14.63   0.000     11631.95    15300.05
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
q99          |
       _cons |      15906    875.695    18.16   0.000     14160.74    17651.26
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. sum price , detail

                            Price
-------------------------------------------------------------
      Percentiles      Smallest
 1%         3291           3291
 5%         3748           3299
10%         3895           3667       Obs                  74
25%         4195           3748       Sum of Wgt.          74

50%       5006.5                      Mean           6165.257
                        Largest       Std. Dev.      2949.496
75%         6342          13466
90%        11385          13594       Variance        8699526
95%        13466          14500       Skewness       1.653434
99%        15906          15906       Kurtosis       4.819188

. cdfplot price , ylab(.01 .05 .1 .25 .5 .75 .9 .95 0.99) xline(3291 3748 3895 4195 5006.5 6342 11385 13466 15906, lcolor(gs15)) xlab(#12)
(0 observations deleted)
```

The cdf looks like this:

[image]